# How to random rows from Billion rows dataset in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataset of 200 Billion rows and I want to extract 1 million rows randomly to start working on data model.

I am using pyspark.

What should be the best way to handle a billion rows?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [sample](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.sample) method on a dataframe.

For example:

```
# Create a 0.0005% sample without replacement, with a random seed of 42
# (1 million/200 billion) = 0.000005
>>> df.sample(withReplacement=False, fraction=0.000005, seed=42).count()
```